# Print range of accuracy for a Logistic Regression model

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have my Logistic Regression model trained on a range of n-grams, let's say from 1 to 5, generated by a TfidfVectorizer. On the other hand I have the accuracy of the model for each fold (since I'm using Kfolds to train the model). I'm trying to plot my model's accuracy with matplotlib (plt) but I don't understand how to use the library to correctly display on the x axis EACH n-gram group (1-gram, 2-gram, 3-gram, ...) and on the y axis the accuracy. I've tried, just to do some tests

```py
# the following 2 lines are used to generate the accuracy score
preds = model.predict(xtest)
accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(test_df.values, preds)

plt.plot(accuracy)
plt.show()
```

But this code seems to plot a blank graphic, only axes labels and parameters are shown.
The shape of the plot should be linear I guess, since the highest n-gram means the better accuracy.
Is it possibile to print the n-gram groups one by one even if they are used as a range (1,5)?

`accuracy` plotting result:
[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPiZz.png)

Comment: can you print out `accuracy`?

Comment: accuracy is a value between 0 and 1. For example with range (1,5) is about 0,91-0,93, with range (1,1) is around 0,65 and so on.

Comment: What do you expect when you plot a single value? The simplest thing you can plot is a point which has 2 values, x and y. A single number cant be charted. So, if your accuracy variable contains a single value, you will get a blank plot.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to plot accuracy against ngram_range, that would require re-fitting the TFidfVectorizer and subsequently the estimator using different values for ngram_range. Is this your objective?

Comment: Referred to the last comment: 
yes, I guess so. My goal is to generate a (x,y) chart with accuracy on y-axis and ngram on the x-axis. Since the interesting data for me are just the ones from one particular range I'm going to consider only that ones, I don't want to re-fit my TfidfVectorizer.

Comment: When using the ngram_range parameter for the TfidfVectorizer, you cant' access individual n-gram groups from the generated matrix. Therefore, in order to assess the impact of a particular n-gram group or range, you will have to re-fit and re-evaluate. For example, you cant' get just unigrams if your ngram_range was (1,5) as you've specified 5 to be the maximum ngram